# How apply custom font to string in resource?

Tags: java, android

I have in resourse  `<string-array name="channel_names">`
and ID

```
 <string-array name="channel_id">
    <item>UCWUi0SCvgAGNJyS3Jmfibow</item>
 </string-array>
```

or can not use a custom font for an array of strings?
In class:

```
         @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
      Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/Arvo-BoldItalic.ttf");
                    channelNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.channel_names);
                    I do not understand what to use? .setTypeface(channelNames,font);



resourse


      <string-array name="channel_names">
            <item>TEXT</item>
                </string-array>

I use navigation Drawer:
I do not have the xml file for the navigation drawer I draw to code
      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);




        layoutList = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        fragmentVideo = (FragmentVideo) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);

        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/Arvo-BoldItalic.ttf");


        channelNames = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.channel_names);


         .setTypeface(channelNames,font);

        channelId = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.channel_id);
        videoTypes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.video_types);

        checkYouTubeApi();

        PrimaryDrawerItem[] primaryDrawerItems = new PrimaryDrawerItem[channelId.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < channelId.length; i++) {
            primaryDrawerItems[i] =
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(channelNames[i]).withIdentifier(i)
                            .withSelectable(false);
        }

        AccountHeader accountHeader = new AccountHeaderBuilder().withActivity(this)
                .withHeaderBackground(R.drawable.header).build();

        drawer = new DrawerBuilder(this).withActivity(ActivityHome.this)
                .withAccountHeader(accountHeader).withDisplayBelowStatusBar(true)
                .withToolbar(toolbar).withActionBarDrawerToggleAnimated(true)
                .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState).addDrawerItems(primaryDrawerItems)
                .addStickyDrawerItems(new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(getString(R.string.about))
                        .withIdentifier(channelId.length - 1).withSelectable(false))
                .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                        selectedDrawerItem = position;
                        if (drawerItem != null) {
                            if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() >= 0 && selectedDrawerItem != -1) {

                                setToolbarAndSelectedDrawerItem(
                                        channelNames[selectedDrawerItem - 1],
                                        (selectedDrawerItem - 1));

                                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                bundle.putString(Utils.TAG_VIDEO_TYPE,
                                        videoTypes[selectedDrawerItem - 1]);
                                bundle.putString(Utils.TAG_CHANNEL_ID,
                                        channelId[selectedDrawerItem - 1]);

                                fragment = new FragmentChannelVideo();
                                fragment.setArguments(bundle);

                                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                        .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
                            } else if (selectedDrawerItem == -1) {
                                Intent aboutIntent =
                                        new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityAbout.class);
                                startActivity(aboutIntent);
                                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.open_next, R.anim.close_main);
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                }).withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState).withShowDrawerOnFirstLaunch(true).build();

        setToolbarAndSelectedDrawerItem(channelNames[0], 0);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(Utils.TAG_VIDEO_TYPE, videoTypes[selectedDrawerItem]);
        bundle.putString(Utils.TAG_CHANNEL_ID, channelId[selectedDrawerItem]);

        fragment = new FragmentChannelVideo();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();

        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onBackStackChanged() {
                        Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager()
                                .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
                        if (f != null) {
                            updateTitleAndDrawer(f);
                        }

                    }
                });

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            drawer.setSelection(0, false);
        }

    }
```

I do not have the xml file for the navigation drawer I draw to code

Comment: I didn't find any method like `setTypeface(String[] strs, Typeface tf)`. For more about `TextView` you may follow https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html/TextView.html

Comment: @Md Sufi Khan
not work